# "expected expression in container literal" in a while loop XCODE

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsurlsession

i have a problem with my code when i try to use this

```
import Foundation
import WebKit



let beaches: [String: Beach] = [
    /* Mate Asher */


var i  = 25
while i <= 30
{
i = i + 1 as string!
let urlPath = ("http://web.com/a.php?id=" + i + "&get=name")
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in})

let urlPath2 = ("http://web.com/a.php?id=" + i + "&get=area")
let url2: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath2)!
let session2 = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task2 = session.dataTaskWithURL(url2, completionHandler: {data2, response, error -> Void in})

let urlPath3 = ("web.com/a.php?id=" + i + "&get=longi")
let url3: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath3)!
let session3 = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task3 = session.dataTaskWithURL(url3, completionHandler: {data3, response, error -> Void in})

"a": Beach(title: data, desc: data2, latitude: 33.080512, longitude: data3),

}
]
```

i get at the var line the error 
"expected expression in container literal"
can some one help please !?

Comment: Wow. A ton of problems here. But error message is informing you that you've started a dictionary literal with `[`, but you then have code in there rather than an expression.

Comment: There are other, deep problems here, too: You never start your requests; you appear to want the results synchronously, but you're initiating asynchronous requests. Frankly, I'd suggest redesigning the web service to reduce the number of separate requests you're issuing (e.g. write a web service that returns all three properties for a given id; even better, write one that returns an array of ids with their associated properties). You'll pay significant performance penalty issuing all of these separate requests and will face a nightmare trying to meld them all together in a single dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to do any kind of looping/condition making block of codes while creating Array's or Dictionary. For that you need to execute that piece of code outside, create a variable and use it.

Comment: Well that's annoying :(

Comment: @NathanF. Alternatively, you can embed arbitrary statements inside of an Array/Dictionary's literal (initializer statement) by wrapping the code in an immediately-called closure, like most other OO languages with closures/lambdas (JavaScript, C#, Java, Kotlin, Ruby, etc.).  In Swift, that would look like this: `{ var someValue = someThing(); let somethingElse = doSomething(someValue); return somethingElse }()`— notice the `()` at the end.  I often choose to nest init/calc code with immediately-called closures b/c then the indentation of code matches the hierarchy of the resulting object graph.